# msbuild resource type for Concourse

Tags: concourse

Are there any resource type for msbuild in Concourse? I am looking to compile and run unit tests for the C# app. As of now I have the msbuild in .cmd file and calling it into the task.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are doing is the correct procedure. Code builds and tests go into Concourse tasks.

A Concourse resource is to push an output (eg: put an artifact to S3) or to pull an input (eg clone a git repo), not to build code.

Comment: I have written a powershell script that I will be calling it into the tasks.